# Specific style on an ordered list

Tags: html, css

I'd like some help to integrate a design made on sketch 2 years ago ! The goal is to do a beautiful orderer list but I have difficulties to integrate the content.

This is what i've done so far :

HTML :

```
<div class="stepbar_block">
    <ol class="stepbar_list">
    <li class="stepbar_list_elem_active"> 50% </li>
    <li class="stepbar_list_item">60% </li>
    <li class="stepbar_list_item">70%</li>
    <li class="stepbar_list_elem_current">80%</li>
    <li class="stepbar_list_item">90%</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.stepbar_block {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: step;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.stepbar_block:before {
  width: 1px;
  height :10px;
  background-color : rgba(87,87,86,0.3);
  content : '';
  position : absolute;
  left : 30px;
  top : -4px;
}

.stepbar_block:after {
  width: 1px;
  height :10px;
  background-color : rgba(87,87,86,0.3);
  content : '';
  position : absolute;
  right : 30px;
  top : -4px;
}

.stepbar_list li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height : 5px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: Roboto;  
  font-size: 10px;  
  line-height: 11px;    
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(87,87,86,0.5);
}

.stepbar_list:after {
    content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(87,87,86,0.3);
  left: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.stepbar_list li:before {
  content : '';
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  background-color : black;
  border-radius: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: -2px auto 10px auto;
}

.stepbar_list_item:after {
  content: counter(step);
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  background-color: white;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: rgba(87,87,86,0.5);    
    font-size: 10px;    
  line-height: 11px;    text-align: center;
}

.stepbar_list_elem_active:after {
    content: counter(step);
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  background-color: red;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.stepbar_list_elem_current:after {
    content: counter(step);
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zawt9hL6/

However I'm able to colorise the items but not the circles, so I'd like to know what is missing because when I play with :before and :after it seems to colorize the whole list item and not a specific content

That is the result i'd like to have

[image]

It is possible to have a render like this ? Moreover it's a gradiant background on the circles..

THank you for advices

Comment: Well you need to only format the before/after elements of the specific item you are dealing with ... If you are using `.stepbar_list_elem_current:after` to get the blue color for the 4th item, then you need to use that same class selector with the :before element as well. But you need to pay attention to specificity as well, because you used `.stepbar_list li:before` to get those circles in the first place - so sth. like `.stepbar_list li.stepbar_list_elem_current:before`, https://jsfiddle.net/zawt9hL6/1/

Comment: @TLR So your question is how to create that circle with gradient?

Comment: Indeed, I wrote it quickly. Since the circles are done in a before and not in 2 div elems as I do usally

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this for all.

```
.stepbar_list_elem_active:before {
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   background-color: #fff;
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: -6px;
   border: 2px solid red;
   border-radius: 50%;
   right: 0;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements to create that circle with gradient. First you can create just regular circle with gradient and then add one more white circle with other pseudo-element on top of the frist one.

```css
10* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 50px;
}

ul:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: gray;
}

li {
  padding: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

li:after, 
li.color:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 40%);
  z-index: 1;
}
li.color:after {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 9px);
}

li.color:before {
  background: white;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

li.yellow:after {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(240,184,88,1) 0%, rgba(230,139,60,1) 38%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 71%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
}

li.blue:after {
   background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(52,163,247,1) 0%, rgba(52,163,247,1) 32%, rgba(19,100,158,1) 71%, rgba(19,100,158,1) 100%);
}

.yellow {
  color: #ED4620;
}

.blue {
  color: #64A3D1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="color yellow">2</li>
  <li class="color blue">3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thats a good start, the things differs that the numbers comes from the counter-step of the ordered list and so another content is displayed below each point